# Passing multi-dimensional NumPy array vs list to fit() throws error

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm experimenting w/conv layers. I want to input two 192x192x3 images, concatenate them, and then do some other stuff. The model summary looks like this:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_40 (InputLayer)           (None, 192, 192, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_41 (InputLayer)           (None, 192, 192, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_7 (Concatenate)     (None, 192, 192, 6)  0           input_40[0][0]                   
                                                                 input_41[0][0]
```

The `shape` of my two inputs look like this: `(1, 192, 192, 3)`

If I pass a `list()` to the `fit()` method, it works fine, ie: `model.fit([input1, input2], ...)` it works fine. However, if I first convert to a NumPy array: `np_array = np.asarray([input1, input2])` with the shape being `(2, 1, 192, 192, 3)` the `fit()` method blows up with this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[[[1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1.],
          ...,
          [1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1.]],

         [[1., 1., 1.],
          [1.,...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: when you pass `np.asarray([input1, input2])` it has wrong shape. there's not much more to say about it

Comment: Actually, if you look at the `shape` from the output of the line you showed and then do a bunch of `len()`s against the original list the shape is the same.

Comment: Passing them as a list of numpy arrays is the correct way, what is the issue with it?

Comment: The issue is I'd like to do a SHAP analysis on the results and the `DeepExplainer` definitely seems to want something with a `shape()` so eventually I'll need to convert the list.

Answer (score 0):

When passing data to multiple inputs, it should be list of arrays instead of one large array. Is there any reason you need to pass it as an array?

Comment: I'm trying to pass TWO images in to be able to `Concatenate()` them in the model to run a `Conv2D` over them. So I need both images at the same time. Also, FWIU, I have to pass in my `X` variable as an array, ie even if I'm passing in one number to the `fit()` it must be in an array.

Comment: Im not sure what you are trying to say? You can pass two images with a list, whats the problem? You will be getting them at the same time as they refer to the two different inputs. Try looking at this: [link](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/). It doesn't have to be an array if you have multiple inputs, which you do.

Comment: Well, I wrote a long reply explaining why but it wouldn't let me post it. Short answer is, no, no it won't work-- it wants four dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion. I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
# Create two inputs of shape (2,2,3)
input1 = np.arange(12)
input1 = input1.reshape([2,2,3])
input1.shape 
(2, 2, 3)
input2 = input1.copy()
input2.shape 
(2, 2, 3)
# Use depth wise stack function numpy.dstack(tup)
input_stacked = np.dstack([input1,input2])
input_stacked.shape
(2, 2, 6)
# Then, you put it into a list and convert it using np.asarray
inputs =  np.asarray([input_stacked,input_stacked,input_stacked,input_stacked])
inputs.shape
(4, 2, 2, 6)
```